# Create new nodes for the children and copy parent info using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have a requirement, need to copy all of parent node info for each child reference nodes. can't figure out on my own. Any help will be highly appreciated. Here is the transformation code. Need to copy all the information from parent for each "**Relationship_410**".

```
 <xsl:template match="/ns0:Records" mode="pass2">
        <Records xmlns="http://www.tech.com/">
          <xsl:for-each select="ns0:Record">
            <xsl:for-each select="ns0:Relationship_397">
 <xsl:for-each select="ns0:Relationship_410">
              <Record>           
                <xsl:copy-of select="./node()[not(self::ns0:Relationship_410)]"></xsl:copy-of>
              </Record>
 </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </Records>
      </xsl:template>
```

**INPUT:**

```
 <Records>
    <Record>
      <Tracking_ID>7</Tracking_ID>
      <Relationship_397>
        <Field_contentId>12099237</Field_contentId>       
        <Relationship_410>
          <Field_contentId>12102605</Field_contentId>          
          <Issue_Criticality>
            <Item>High</Item>
          </Issue_Criticality>         
        </Relationship_410>
            <Relationship_410>
          <Field_contentId>test -- 12102605</Field_contentId>         
          <Issue_Criticality>
            <Item>test --High</Item>
          </Issue_Criticality>          
        </Relationship_410>
        <Relationship_49>
          <Field_contentId>7358689</Field_contentId>
          <Tracking_ID>7358689</Tracking_ID>
        </Relationship_49>          
      </Relationship_397>
      <Relationship_124>
        <Field_contentId>5981551</Field_contentId>       
      </Relationship_124>
      <Relationship_124>
        <Field_contentId>5985378</Field_contentId>        
      </Relationship_124>
    </Record>
  </Records>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 <Records>
  <Record>
    <Tracking_ID>7</Tracking_ID>
    <Relationship_397>
      <Field_contentId>12099237</Field_contentId>
      <Relationship_410>
        <Field_contentId>12102605</Field_contentId>
        <Issue_Criticality>
          <Item>High</Item>
        </Issue_Criticality>
      </Relationship_410>
      <Relationship_49>
        <Field_contentId>7358689</Field_contentId>
        <Tracking_ID>7358689</Tracking_ID>
      </Relationship_49>
    </Relationship_397>
    <Relationship_124>
      <Field_contentId>5981551</Field_contentId>
    </Relationship_124>
    <Relationship_124>
      <Field_contentId>5985378</Field_contentId>
    </Relationship_124>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <Tracking_ID>7</Tracking_ID>
    <Relationship_397>
      <Field_contentId>12099237</Field_contentId>
      <Relationship_410>
        <Field_contentId>test -- 12102605</Field_contentId>
        <Issue_Criticality>
          <Item>test --High</Item>
        </Issue_Criticality>
      </Relationship_410>
      <Relationship_49>
        <Field_contentId>7358689</Field_contentId>
        <Tracking_ID>7358689</Tracking_ID>
      </Relationship_49>
    </Relationship_397>
    <Relationship_124>
      <Field_contentId>5981551</Field_contentId>
    </Relationship_124>
    <Relationship_124>
      <Field_contentId>5985378</Field_contentId>
    </Relationship_124>
  </Record>
</Records>
```

Comment: Could you please minimize the example to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem? See: [mcve]

Comment: I have deleted all the unnecessary stuff. Sorry about that. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: This is still quite confusing, because your XSLT references nodes in a namespace, and your XML has none. I have posted an answer based solely on the shown input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICT, the required output can be produced quite easily by:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Records">
    <Records>
        <xsl:for-each select="//Relationship_410">
            <Record>
                <xsl:copy-of select="../../Tracking_ID"/>
                <Relationship_397>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="../../Relationship_397/Field_contentId"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="../Relationship_49"/>
                </Relationship_397>
                <xsl:copy-of select="../../Relationship_124"/>
            </Record>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Records>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Mike for providing easy to understand solution.

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this:

```
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:param name="r410" />
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" >
              <xsl:with-param name="r410" select="$r410" />
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>  
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Relationship_410"> 
      <xsl:param name="r410" />
      <xsl:if test="$r410 = generate-id(.)" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates  />
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/Records"> 
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//Relationship_410" mode="gen410" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Relationship_410" mode="gen410">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::Record">
        <xsl:with-param name="r410" select="generate-id(.)" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
```